# Matlab: same x axis for different histograms

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have different histograms I created using the hist function, which range differently along the x axis but they are all of the same order of magnitude.

Now I want to sum up the y values of the histograms into a new vector and plot the new histogram on a reasonable x axis which I'm having trouble to create.

It needs to be coherent with the y values, meaning, say there were five counts on the value 0.1 which is in the 3rd spot on a certain x axis vector and ten counts on same value which is located now in the 100th spot along another x axis vector. It needs to show 15 counts on the 0.1 value on the final x axis.

Please help!

Comment: You'd need to make sure that the histogram _x_ values are _exactly the same_, otherwise you can't add the _y_ values. The best way to do that is to _compute a histogram of the two sets of data merged_. Something like `hist([data1(:); data2(:)], nbins)`

Comment: Or you can set the exact bin widths and add the two results column wise, see the example in the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html)